# Specifying Extended Resources in Kubelet Configuration

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubelet

Is it possible to specify extended resources in Kubelet configuration or would this need to be achieved using something like a daemon pod?

An extended resource in this context refers to this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/extended-resource-node/. This page specifies that the way to advertise these resources is to send a patch to the nodes `/status` endpoint like so:

`curl --header "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" \
--request PATCH \
--data '[{"op": "add", "path": "/status/capacity/example.com~1dongle", "value": "4"}]' \
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/nodes/<your-node-name>/status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to specify extended resources in Kubelet configuration
>   or would this need to be achieved using something like a daemon pod?

No, **extended resources** cannot be specified just in **Kubelet** configuration. If you want to configure them permanently, you can use **[Device Plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/device-plugins/)**.

> You can deploy a device plugin as a `DaemonSet`, as a package for your
>   node’s operating system, or manually.
>
> The canonical directory `/var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins` requires
>   privileged access, so a device plugin must run in a privileged
>   security context. If you’re deploying a device plugin as a `DaemonSet`,
>   `/var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins` must be mounted as a Volume in the
>   plugin’s PodSpec.
>
> If you choose the `DaemonSet` approach you can rely on Kubernetes to:
>   place the device plugin’s `Pod` onto `Nodes`, to restart the daemon `Pod`
>   after failure, and to help automate upgrades.